# Como criar abas para navegador no Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Olá!, Estou criando um navegador para Android usando Android Studio estou tentando criar um recurso que tem em todos navegador que são as múltiplas abas como do Google Chrome, mas estou sem sorte e todas minhas tentativas estão falhando, alguém sabe como criar abas para navegador Android? Como o Google Chrome, uc Browser etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim. Pode criar um adaptador com fragmentos adicionáveis.

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /**Adds a fragment and corresponding title to the list*/
    public void addFragment(Fragment f, String title){
        mFragmentList.add(f);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

E adicionar um viewpager que não permite deslizar entre fragmentos:

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    //down one is added for smooth scrolling

    private void setMyScroller() {
        try {
            Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
            Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scroller.setAccessible(true);
            scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
        public MyScroller(Context context) {
            super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
        }

        @Override
        public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
            super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 350 /*1 secs*/);
        }
    }
}
```

Faça setup no onCreate da atividade:

```
// Sets up the ViewPager with the sections adapter
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
setupViewPager();
```

Use esta função para setup:

```
/**Sets up the custom viewpager*/
private void setupViewPager(){
    // here we set up our own adapter...
    MyAdapter adapter= new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // ...add the fragments we want...
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "First");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentTwo(), "Second");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentThree(), "Third");

    // ...and set up our own adapter on the viewpager
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Para adicionar fragmentos só tem de chamar addFragment() do adaptador.

Se quiser, pode colocar uma função no ViewPager para apresentar o fragmento que pretende. Algo como:

```
public void showFragment(int fragmentIndex){
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(fragmentIndex);
}
```

Não se esqueça de utilizar o ViewPager correto no layout da atividade.

Pode utilizar as tabs de origem que vêm na biblioteca do Android Studio. Só tem que as fazer interagir com o ViewPager, e apresentar os títulos de acordo.

Espero que ajude.